# What does coroutine mean in Python?

Tags: python, coroutine

Is there a consensus on what a coroutine is today in Python?

I found coroutines first mentioned in PEP [219](https://peps.python.org/pep-0219/) and [220](https://peps.python.org/pep-0220/) (2000, Python 2.1), then in [PEP 255 – Simple Generators](https://peps.python.org/pep-0255/) (2001, Python 2.2). The latter is the PEP that introduced generators and the `yield` statement, which are the basis of coroutines as of [PEP 342 - Coroutines via Enhanced Generators](https://peps.python.org/pep-0342/) (2005, Python 2.5).

If we stop then, a generator that you can send values to is - pretty much - a coroutine:

```
def coroutine():
    name = yield
    print(f"Hello {name}")
    
hello = coroutine()
type(hello)  # generator type
hello.send(None)  # Initialize the coroutine
hello.send("Dave")  # prints 'Hello Dave' (and raises StopIteration)
```

Fast forward to [PEP 492 – Coroutines with async and await syntax](https://peps.python.org/pep-0492/) (2015, Python 3.5), and this is called a coroutine:

```
async def coroutine():
    pass

type(coroutine())  # coroutine
```

Are both of these constructs commonly referred as coroutines, or is there some jargon to distinguish between the two?

Comment: I would say that "coroutine" these days refers to `async def` style coroutines, because with the introduction of the `async` syntax there's no good reason to use the older style of generator-based coroutines.

Comment: `async` still defines somethign of type `async_generator` (at least in CPython). The distinctions to draw here are the difference between a subroutine and a coroutine, and the difference between synchronous and asynchronous. An asynchronous subroutine doesn't really make sense, but the other three combinations can and do exist. (A function is a synchronous subroutine, a `generator` is used to implement a synchronous coroutine, and a `async_generator` is used to implement an asynchronous coroutine.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word *coroutine* can be used in different contexts.

In the more general "computer science" context, it means (e.g. quoting from [coroutine](/questions/tagged/coroutine))

> a general control structure whereby flow control is cooperatively passed between two different routines without returning

In this sense, both Python [*generators*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#index-19) (functions which use `yield`) and Python [*coroutine functions*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-coroutine-function) (functions defined by an `async def` statement) implement coroutines (I'm not sure if they *are* coroutines).

In the more specific Python context, a *coroutine* is what is returned by a *coroutine function*.

Comment: Python generators implement a special case of coroutines, in that a coroutine can *call* any other (co/sub)routine, but can only "return" to the (co/sub)routine that called it (where Python functions implement subroutines). A fully general coroutine would be implemented with something closer to continuations.

Comment: So in Python "coroutine" is a recursive term? What is a coroutine function? A function that is returned by a function that is returned by a function that is... ?

Answer (score 0):

Reading PEP 492 I found a clue to the answer.

> [...] we use the word *native coroutine* to refer to functions declared using the new syntax [i.e. using `async def`]. *generator-based coroutine* is used where necessary to refer to coroutines that are based on generator syntax. *coroutine* is used in contexts where both definitions are applicable.